# RMO on Windows 7 - The Specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, rmo-programming

**My machine:**
Windows XP (x86), VS2008, .net 3.5, sql server 2005, WinForms  -> App works fine.

**Production Machines:**  Windows 7 (x64), SQl Server 2005 Express -> App Starts but throws exception

**Visual Studio**  Targeting x86 on setup project and RMO project. Visual Studio gives me a a couple warnings but I can still build:

```
Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER' (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='10.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'

Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER' (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='10.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider.dll'
```

This is a simple RMO (Replication Management Objects) app that initiates a pull subscription in SQL Server 2005 and displays status. Works fine on my machine, but fails on the production machine. I'm using a setup project to install the app on the production machine, but I think I'm missing a dependency somewhere, but I can't figure it out. 
On the production machine the app starts fine, but when I try to synch the subscription i get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Specified module could not be found. (Exception from HResult: 0x8007007E)
```

**EDIT:**  Task Manager in Win 7 inditcates that it is running as a 32-bit app (myapp.exe *32).

**EDIT:** Ok, my app is now showing in  task manager that it is a 64 bit app, but I'm getting an error. I'm thinking that I some how have a dependency dll targeting x86.  How can I verify the dependency dll is targeting the correct platfrom and/or make sure that it is targeting x64... I thought the setup prjoect would rebuild the dll in my detected dependencies to target whatever cpu I chose in the setup project?

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture-neutral, PublicKey Token=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. An attempt to was made to load a program  with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 0):

run Fusion Log viewer as administrator and set it to Log Bind Failures to Disk.
that way you'll be able to see which DLL's don't load properly.

Comment: sorry I should have noted that I know which dll it is that is not loading, I just don't know why (see my updated question).

Comment: search for that dll on your machine. could be that it didn't install for some reason.

Comment: yeah, its definitely there. I just think that its not going to work with With a 64bit Win 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the setup prjoect would rebuild the dll in my detected dependencies to target whatever >cpu I chose in the setup project

the setup does not compile any dlls for you automatically.

> An attempt to was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

look here, on where to find an x64 version of 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication'
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreplication/thread/628ec2ae-c5d1-4aef-b31b-b889975bfc2b

Comment: thanks, but eventually ended up going with a slightly different route. I now just start a process and call replmerg.exe and pass in the appropriate arguments to get the handle the replication.